# Is Deque supported in GWT?

Tags: gwt

```
...
private Deque<PagePresenter> pageHistory = new ArrayDeque<PagePresenter>();
...

[ERROR] [test_app] - Line 8: No source code is available for type java.util.Deque<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

do I need to implement it myself?

Thanks,
/S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GWT includes a [`LinkedList`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_util) implementation that implements part of the `Dequeue` interface (`addFirst()`, `getFirst()`, `removeFirst()`, `addLast()`, `getLast()`, `removeLast()`).

If you need a full `Dequeue` implementation you need to implement it (or at least the missing methods on `LinkedList`) yourself.